# TypeError: sheet.appendColumn is not a function

Tags: google-apps-script

Had successfully used appendRow to add a new row, but tried with appendColumn just didn't work. appendColumn is also in Class Table, but why it is not working?

```
function recordValueMarket() {
   var market = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("market");
   var importFromWeb = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("importFromWeb");
  var date = new Date();
  var SYMB1 =importFromWeb.getRange("importFromWeb!E2").getValue();
  var SYMB2 =importFromWeb.getRange("importFromWeb!E3").getValue();
  var SYMB3 =importFromWeb.getRange("importFromWeb!E4").getValue();
     market.appendRow([date, SYMB1, SYMB2, SYMB3]);
}
```

Comment: There is no Sheet.appendColumn().  Class Table is in Document not Spreadsheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to put the values of `date, SYMB1, SYMB2, SYMB3` to the sheet as the append column.

For this, how about this answer?

I thought that `appendColumn` of `appendColumn is also in Class Table,` might be Class Table in Slides service. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/table#appendColumn()) When you want to put the values to Google Spreadsheet as the append column, how about this modification?

#### Modified script 1:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

From:

```
market.appendRow([date, SYMB1, SYMB2, SYMB3]);
```

To:

```
var values = [[date], [SYMB1], [SYMB2], [SYMB3]];
market.getRange(1, market.getLastColumn() + 1, values.length, 1).setValues(values);
```

#### Modified script 2:

In this modification, the values are retrieved from "E2:E4" of the sheet `importFromWeb`. And the retrieved values are put to the sheet `market` as the append column. I think that this process cost is a bit lower from above modified script.

```
function recordValueMarket() {
  var market = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("market");
  var importFromWeb = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("importFromWeb");
  var values = importFromWeb.getRange("E2:E4").getValues();
  values.unshift([new Date()]);
  market.getRange(1, market.getLastColumn() + 1, values.length, 1).setValues(values);
}
```

#### References:

- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))

Comment: @MubieSam Lin Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.